# Acceleration in infinite Atwood's machine

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

Problem:  Consider the inﬁnite Atwood’s machine shown below. A string passes over each pulley, with one end attached to a mass and the other end attached to another pulley. All the masses are equal to m, and all the pulleys and strings are massless. The masses are held ﬁxed and then simultaneously released. What is the acceleration of the top mass?
[image: Atwood's machine]

I don't know how to do this problem with infinite pulleys.
If the tension in the topmost string is $T$ then I get, and $a_1, a_2$ be the acceleration of the first and second masses wrt.the first and second pulleys then I get, 
$\frac{T}{2}-mg=ma_1$ and

$\frac{T}{4}-mg=m(a_2-a_1)$ but I dont know how to proceed. I am beginner at mechanics. 
Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infinite Atwood's machine](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21836/)

Comment: @YashasSamaga no solution is given in that link..its only told that it can be solved by recursive relations. But I can't figure out how. Please help me.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: @Cupid The author of that question himself has posted the solution.

Comment: for petty reasons, good questions are blocked and it's a waste of time because others may want to ask it again